# Convert string to wstring, encoding issues

Tags: c++, string, encode, wstring

I've read Stroustrup's [Appendix D](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/3rd_loc0.html) (particular attention to Locales and Codecvt). Stroustrup does not give a good codecvt and widen example (IMHO). I've been trying to knob turn stuff from the internet with no joy. I've also tried imbue'ing stringstreams without success.

Would anyone be able to show (and explain) the code to go from a UTF-8 to a UTF-16 (or UTF-32) encoding? *NOTE:* I do not know the size of the input/output string in advance, so I expect the solution should use `reserve` and a `back_inserter`. Please don't use `out.resize(in.length()*2)`.

When finished, it would be great if the code actually worked (its amazing how much broken code is out there). Please make sure the following 'round trips'. The bytes below are the Han character for 'bone' in UTF-8 and UTF-{16|32}.

```
const std::string n("\xe9\xaa\xa8");
const std::wstring w = L"\u9aa8";
```

My apologies for a basic question. On Windows, I use the Win32 API and don't have these problems moving between encodings.

Comment: There's nothing at all that says that `wstring` has to be UTF-16 (on Unix, for example, `wchar_t` is typically 32 bits). So it stands to reason that the book doesn't address UTF-16 specifically. Plus, because of astral characters, you will need to specifically deal with surrogate pairs in UTF-16, and ensure that they convert properly to 4-byte UTF-8 sequences (and vice versa).

Comment: Agreed Chris ("There's nothing at all that says that wstring has to be UTF-16"). I believe the only thing required is that wchar_t is at least 8 bits. For what is worth, I don't care if its 4, 8, or 10 bytes - I just want it to convert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems pretty obvious that he was smoking weed. As for the codepage conversions, look no further than [iconv](http://www.gnu.org/s/libiconv/)!

Comment: I'm very close to moving to libiconv. libiconv is not on my Fedora 14 box (though its on my Ubuntu 10 box). I don't want to torture users by asking them to install a bunch of extra libraries. (Instead, I'm torturing myself...).

Comment: @noloader: `libiconv`'s functionality is built into GNU libc. So all Linux systems should already have it.

Answer (score 4):

Just use [UTF8-CPP](http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/) :

```
std::wstring conversion; 
utf8::utf8to16(utf8_str.begin(), utf8_str.end() , back_inserter(conversion));
```

Caveat: this will only work where wchar_t is 2-bytes long (windows).

For a portable solution you could do :

```
std::vector<unsigned short> utf16line; // uint16_t if you can
utf8::utf8to16(utf8_line.begin(), utf8_line.end(), back_inserter(utf16line));
```

But then you're losing the string support. Hopefully, we'll get char16_t soon enough.

Comment: +1: Yes, please, this needs to be used more. The best C++ library I have seen for converting to/from UTF encodings.

Comment: Anno - UTFCPP looks great. It does narrow (UTF-8) and wide (UTF-{16|32}) the way I expect. However, it appears to lack functionality to move to/from the current locale and UTF. Can you confirm?

Comment: Yes, there's no support for other forms of encodings.

Comment: Great,this needs to be used more.I'm looking for a long finally found this.